# Using index to sort documents in Mongo aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to show my documents in a table (like a history in a web page), so I have several search criterias.
Here is my document structure :

```
{
  "_id": "5dcae9defbb1bf46e9162641",
  "idUnykoo": 1,
  "workflowData": [
    {
      "created": "2018-12-26T16:55:39Z[UTC]",
      "login": "AppMov",
      "type": "CONSULTA_SIC",
      "consultaSIC": {
        "id": "1",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "consultaBC": {
          "created": "Nov 26, 2015 4:55:39 PM",
          "user": {
            "id": 1001,
            "login": "AppMov",
            "apellidoPaterno": "marchand",
            "apellidoMaterno": "sand",
            "primerNombre": "alex",
            "email": "alex@toto.com"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "created": "2019-11-12T17:20:15.870Z[UTC]",
      "login": "AppMov",
      "type": "SMS",
      "vprData": {
        "name": "VPR ALEX",
        "dataId": "297065",
        "connectorVprId": "1",
        "data": [
          {
            "dataIndex": 1,
            "name": "Edad",
            "value": "59"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Each element of the workflowData array is an action of a user, and I want to show all the actions of a certain type in an history.

I want to be able to filter my documents by either/and : 
`workflowData.type`
`workflowData.login`
`workflowData.created`

and I want my results sorted in a descending order on `workflowData.created`

I'm trying to do this query :

`db.workfloos.aggregate([{$match:{'workflowData':{$elemMatch:{'type':'CONSULTA_SIC','created':{$gte:'2018-11-26T16:55:39Z[UTC]'},'login':'alex'}}}},{$sort:{'workflowData.created':-1}},{'$limit':500}])`

But it is really really slow, even though I put a multikey index on these keys :

```
    "key" : {
            "idUnykoo" : -1,
            "workflowData.type" : 1,
            "workflowData.created" : 1,
            "workflowData.login" : 1
        }
```

Could someone help me to understand if there is a way I can do this in mongo db with a reasonable response time? I have nearly a million documents, and I can see that the sort is very slow because it seems it can't make use of the index to have the documents already sortes after the match. So it tries to sort all the results of the match.

Thanks

Comment: Couple of points to note: (1) The query may not be using the index properly (hence slow); this is because the index-prefix to be used with the query cannot be applied. The `idUnykoo : -1` in the index definition will not allow usage of index in your query. (2) You are talking a large amount of data, and multi-key indexes can create indexes of larger size; sometimes it can become difficult to load the index into memory, because of the size. I suggest run `explain()` on your query and include the results in the post; this will show if the index is being used properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create indexes on the below fields:

```
db.collectionName.createIndex({"workflowData.created":-1})
db.collectionName.createIndex({"workflowData.type":1, "workflowData.created":-1})
```

I think these indexes on the collection will appropriately handle your aggregation query:

```
db.workfloos.aggregate([{$match:{'workflowData':{$elemMatch:{'type':'CONSULTA_SIC','created':{$gte:'2018-11-26T16:55:39Z[UTC]'},'login':'alex'}}}},{$sort:{'workflowData.created':-1}},{'$limit':500}])
```

For details, kindly visit the official documentation of MongoDB [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#aggregation-pipeline-optimization)

In particular, check this [`$sort` Operator and Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html#sort-operator-and-performance)

Comment: Thanks Krishna for the answer. I tried it but unfortunately this does not solve my problem, the query is taking more than 20s to run.
Even without the clause on 'login', it is slow.
I will update my post with the explain() output.

Comment: Well it seems I can't edit my question, and I can't post all the explain() output in a comment, cause it's too long.

So basically my winning plan is : 
 "inputStage" : {"stage" : "IXSCAN" ...
 "indexBounds" : {"workflowData.type" : ["[\"CONSULTA_SIC\",\"CONSULTA_SIC\"]"],
        "workflowData.created" : [
         "({}, \"2018-11-26T16:55:39Z[UTC]\"]"
        ]
       }
 and then I got a filter stage with an $elemMatch on the same fields...